# Quartz is not working in real server

Tags: c#, asp.net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have access to db and ftp to my live server. I want to schedule a task. I did a schedule in Quartz.net (ASP.Net C#) and it's working fine in the local server, when I upload it to the server I get no out put. I added a file write command to the top and bottom of my task, those files are writing to the destination. Here is the code I wrote

```
public partial class saaiTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestClass t = new TestClass();
        t.method("start");

        ISchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        IScheduler scheduler = factory.GetScheduler();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<TestClass>()
            .WithIdentity("name", "group")
            .Build();

        ITrigger triggerCron = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithCronSchedule("0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *")
            .StartNow()
            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, triggerCron);
        scheduler.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
        scheduler.Shutdown();

        t.method("stop");
    }
}

public class TestClass : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        this.method("job");
    }

    public void method(string filename)
    {
        StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~\\test\\" + filename + ".txt"), true);
        file2.WriteLine("Write Time : " + DateTime.Now);
        file2.Close();
    }
}
```

I started the schedule by running this page, I tried adding this to `Global.asax`. What should I do to start the scheduler in my live server, is it possible to stop the schedule from the server, if so what is the solution ?

Comment: If you add Quartz to your application thats run on IIS server then it will be stopped sooner or later and Quartz will stop too. So in my opinion best solutions for this kind of operations is to create local service with Quartz jobs and run it on your live server as local service

Comment: Had you checked that asp.net has permission to write files in this folder?

Comment: @derloopkat yes, to check that I tried to write two file at the top and bottom, they are written to the folder

Comment: @Marcin I have access to db and ftp, how can I run as a local service ?

Comment: when you go to your bin folder at server, can you see quartz dll there?

Comment: Check this out: [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/WebControls/] or this [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/WebControls/] or [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106742/WebControls/]. It should be simple local service which must be install by MSUtil and in this service you can use your standard Qurtz.net schedulers and job. And you will be sure that this service starts always with server.

Comment: @derloopkat yes there is

Comment: I'd recommend to check your Windows Events at server. If there's nothing there, then add try/catch blocks to your code and log all errors to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this link would give you what you need [Simulate a Windows Service using ASP.NET to run scheduled jobs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc)

Quartz uses windows services, use [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) instead which doesn't need windows services. This [Hangfire, a must for adding background tasks in ASP.NET](http://www.frictionlesscode.com/hangfire-a-must-for-adding-background-tasks-in-asp-net/) link would help you get started

Comment: This is the best solution only when you don't have access to server and you are not able to install service on it. In all other cases scheduled jobs should be started from windows service.

Comment: It depends on the use you want to give your scheduler. If you need to do something critical at a specific time that may be an issue. The problem is IIS will recycle your thread and clear your cache (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314939/asp-net-cache-and-recycle-worker-processes). The solution given in Codeproject article for that problem ("adding your website to search engines") is dodgy and does not guaranty that a thread will be running overnight. Of course you can disable recycling and make your website unstable. If no request is received the server will sleep and won't do anything.

Comment: when you have access to db and ftp, this is a better solution